Check if a code is cyclic and find its generator polynomial
Let $C$ be a code over $\mathbb{Z}_7$ with the generator matrix
$ G = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \newline
1 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $
I would like to find out if the code is cyclic and, if it is cyclic, its generator polynomial. The code has $7^3 = 343$ elements, so it's not practical to write them all out.
I know the third row is a cyclic shift from the second row and while trying to get its control matrix I was able to get it in this form:
$ G = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 \newline
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 4 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $
However $1 + 3x + 4x^2$ does not divide $t^6 - 1 = t^6 + 6$ over $Z_7$. I've also checked for $1 + 4x + 4x^3$ and that doesn't work either. Does this prove its not cyclic? I'm not sure how to progress.

In fact this is not a cyclic code because the last coordinate is zero, the problem is that some rows are missing. It should be 5 rows I think. I am leaving my previous answer in case it helps.

I understand the second matrix is another generating matrix, not a control matrix. Since $\gcd(1 + 3x + 4x^2,\ x^6 - 1) = x + 3,$
$$\langle 1 + 3x + 4x^2 \rangle = \langle x + 3\rangle$$
as elements of $\mathbb Z_7[x]/\langle x^6 - 1 \rangle.$ Thus $x + 3$ is the polynomial that you want.
In general, a matrix of this type always generates a cyclic code, because it generates an ideal, but if you want the unique generating element that divides $x^6 - 1$ you have to take the $\gcd.$
